# Content div going over fixed navbar

Tags: css

I've got a stylesheet where the intention is to have a fixed navbar which stays at the top of the screen no matter how far you scroll down. For this I've just used `position:fixed;` - but when I actually scroll down, the `#content` div overrides it and goes straight over the top (so the navbar stays at the top of the page but is underneath the content div.)

I haven't done any serious CSS coding in years, so I'm a bit rusty - it's probably a very simple solution, so apologies for being so trivial!

**style.css**

```
body {
    margin:0;
    background:#eeeeee;
}

#navbar {
    background-color:#990000;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:50px;
    top:0px;
}

#navbar a {
    color:#fff;
}

#content {
    background:#eeeeee;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;
}

#feed {
    background: #fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:22%;
    width:776px;
}
```

**Pages are structured like this:**

```
<body>
    <div id="navbar"><?php include core/navbar.php; ?></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="feed">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In order to fix this you need the property `z-index`[defined by W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) that specify the level of the element. Try this:

```
#navbar {
  background-color:#990000;
  position:fixed;  
  z-index:1; /*Add this*/
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  line-height:50px;
  top:0px;
}
```

Comment: 2018 and this still works like a charm. Thank you @DaniP

Comment: 2020 and it works. I guess we are all missing the Z-Index

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Bootstrap 4, the .navbar background is clear and can be covered by some elements.  Setting the z-index won't work.  Use a background color, e.g., .bg-white.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-white">
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the override issue use **CSS z-index Property**
z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) .

```
#navbar {
background-color:#990000;
position:fixed;
z-index: 1;
width:100%;
height:50px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:50px;
top:0px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you use z-index -1 in order not to let the element pass over the fixed nav bar this thing solves the problem but at the same time another problem arises, now on the element which we gave z-index:-1, hover will not work.
So to take care of these things we must use index 0 at the element and in the fixed nav bar we need to use z index 1. then all things will be sorted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).